# I cant extract a link from a HTML-code with Python and BeautifulSoup (beginner)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm a complete beginner with webscraping and programming with Python. The answer might be somewhere at the forum, but i'm so new, that i dont really now, what to look for. So i hope, you can help me:

Last week I completed a three day course in webscraping with Python, and at the moment i'm trying to brush up on what i've learned so far.

I'm trying to scrape out a spcific link from a website, so that i later on can create a loop, that extracts all the other links. But i can't seem to extract any link even though they are visible in the HTML-code.

- [Here is the website (danish](https://stpk.dk/afgorelser-og-domme/afgorelser-fra-styrelsen-for-patientklager/))
- [Here is the link i'm trying to extract](https://stpk.dk/afgorelser-og-domme/afgorelser-fra-styrelsen-for-patientklager/22sfp108/)

The link i'm trying extract is located in this html-code:

`<a class="nav-action-arrow-underlined" href="/afgorelser-og-domme/afgorelser-fra-styrelsen-for-patientklager/22sfp108/" aria-label="Læs mere om Regionen tilbød ikke"\>Læs mere\</a\>`

Here is the programming in Python, that i've tried so far:

```
url = "https://stpk.dk/afgorelser-og-domme/afgorelser-fra-styrelsen-for-patientklager/"

r = requests.get(url)
html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
a_tags = soup.find_all("a") len(a_tags)
```

#there is 34
've then tried going through all "a-tags" from 0-33 without finding the link.

If i'm printing `a_tags [26]` - i'm getting this code:

`<a aria-current="page" class="nav-action is-current" href="/afgorelser-og-domme/afgorelser-fra-styrelsen-for-patientklager/"\>Afgørelser fra Styrelsen for Patientklager\</a\>` 
Which is somewhere at the top of the website. But the next `a_tag [27]` is a code at the bottom of the site:

``` <a class="footer-linkedin" href="``https://www.linkedin.com/company/styrelsen-for-patientklager/``" rel="noopener" target="_blank" title="``https://www.linkedin.com/company/styrelsen-for-patientklager/``"><span class="sr-only">Linkedin profil</span></a> ```

---

Can anyone help me by telling me, how to access the specific part of the HTML-code, that contains the link?

When i find out how to pull out the link, my plan is to make the following programming:

```
path = "/afgorelser-og-domme/afgorelser-fra-styrelsen-for-patientklager/22sfp108/"
full_url = f"htps://stpk.dk{path}"
print(full_url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not find what you are looking for, cause `requests` do not render websites like a browser will do - but no worry, there is an alterntive.

Content is dynamically loaded via api, so you should call these directly and you will get JSON that contains the displayed information.

> *To find such information take a closer look into the developer tools of your browser and check the tab for the `XHR Requests` - May take a
> minute to read and follow the topic:
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/XHR_(XMLHttpRequest)*

Simply iterate over the `items`, extract the `url` value and prepend the `base_url`.

Check and manipulate the following parameters to your needs:

```
containerKey: a76f4a50-6106-4128-bc09-a1da7695902b
query: 
year: 
category: 
legalTheme: 
specialty: 
profession: 
treatmentPlace: 
critiqueType: 
take: 200
skip: 0
```

##### Example

```
import requests

url = 'https://stpk.dk/api/verdicts/settlements/?containerKey=a76f4a50-6106-4128-bc09-a1da7695902b&query=&year=&category=&legalTheme=&specialty=&profession=&treatmentPlace=&critiqueType=&take=200&skip=0'
base_url = 'https://stpk.dk'
for e in requests.get(url).json()['items']:
    print(base_url+e['url'])
```

##### Output

```
https://stpk.dk/afgorelser-og-domme/afgorelser-fra-styrelsen-for-patientklager/22sfp108/
https://stpk.dk/afgorelser-og-domme/afgorelser-fra-styrelsen-for-patientklager/22sfp107/
https://stpk.dk/afgorelser-og-domme/afgorelser-fra-styrelsen-for-patientklager/22sfp106/
https://stpk.dk/afgorelser-og-domme/afgorelser-fra-styrelsen-for-patientklager/22sfp105/
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Okay, i can see that they have changed the website, since i took the course, because this is totally new to me. When i open my XHR tab, it just stays blank when i enter the site. I'm not getting any info regarding containerkey etc. 

Do you now where i can read/learn more about this particular problem - is there a particular name that i can search for to get tutorials abiut this?

Comment: Check my anwer for the link to get closer to the topic - The tab may be empty, cause the website starts with a default from a script - Check the tab again after scrolling down and click for mor results. This should give you an idea, what happens.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will dig deeper into this. Thanks again!